# Why this solution isn't working for the coin change algorithm?(Garbage Value)

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

How many different ways can you make change for an amount, given a list of coins?
Write a program that, given

The amount  to make change for and the number of types  of infinitely available coins
A list of  coins - 
Prints out how many different ways you can make change from the coins to STDOUT.

I tried with various input.I am getting garbage value as answer for input 
10(N) 4(M)
2 5 3 6
Please explain?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#define MAX 200
using namespace std;


long long coinchange(int coin[],int m,int n)// n =N
{
long long total[m][n+1];
/*
for(int j=0;j<m;j++)    {
    for(int i=0;j<n+1;i++)   {
        total[j][i] = 0;
    }
}
*/

for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
    total[j][0] = 1;

for(int i=0;i<m;i++) {
    for(int j=1;j<n+1;j++)  {
        if(j>=coin[i])
            total[i][j] = total[i-1][j] + total[i][j-coin[i]];
        else
            total[i][j] = total[i-1][j];
    }
}
return total[m-1][n];
}

int main() {
   int N,M;
   cin>>N;
   cin>>M;
   int coin[MAX];
   for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
      cin>>coin[i];
   cout<<coinchange(coin, M, N)<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your double loop you're accessing -1 element for `i=0` in the first loop run

Comment: Consider the combination of `for(int i=0;` with `total[i-1][j]`.

Comment: i also tried with for(int i=1;i<=m;i++) but that also didn't work